# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: club

Tags: python, html, sql, sqlite, flask

I've been trying to get this line of code to work, but for some reason, even when I inserted the absolute path, it's not recognizing the tables in `site.db`. I checked the database and the tables were there.

I've tried using the absolute path and I've tried changing around the db.Model, but it's not fixing the issue. Capitalization and spelling are also probably not the issue.

**routes.py**

```
@clubs.route('/edit_clubs/<int:user_id>/<int:club_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def user_clubs_edit(user_id, club_id):
    user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)
    clubs = user.clubs
    id=str(club_id)

    # create cursor
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "site.db")
    with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as db:
        cur = db.cursor()

        # get club by id
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM club WHERE id= ?", id)

        club = cur.fetchone()
        cur.close()
```

**models.py**

```
class Club(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    members = db.relationship('User', secondary=user_club_assoc_table)
    contacts = db.Column(db.Text)
    minutes = db.relationship('Minutes', backref='club')
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'#Club(name={self.name!r})
```

I want to get the `club` from the table with the given id.

Comment: yes, the tables were created in site.db when I checked.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with this code, I created a database file named site.db and tested it with your code and it worked just fine.  The table must not exist.